# HAC Robust Errors - Simple Static Time Series Regression

Tags: time-series, multivariate-regression, neweywest, hac

We're working with Wooldridge Econometrics without matrix algebra.

My professor introduces a simple static time series model:
$$y_t = \beta_0 +\beta_1x_t+u_t$$

In the presence of serial correlation, we adjust for variance with the presence of autocorrelation:

$$Var(\sum_{t=1}^nw_tu_t | X) = \sum_{t=1}^nVar(w_tu_t|X) + \sum_{t=1}^n\sum_{s\neq t}^nCov(w_tu_t, w_su_s | X)$$

I'm good up to here, but how do we adjust this formula and get 'autocorrelation adjusted' variances in the case of a multivariate model with more than one parameter (Where the formula for $\beta_i$ may be a bit more involved (Regression Anatomy))?